# android navigation drawer layout how to cover over the support actionbar?

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

There was a problem with my navigation drawer It was not cover over the support action bar **because** I am using **`androidmanifest.xml`** to set the `actionbar` with `android:theme="@style/custom_actionbar"` by using **`style.xml`** on the activity, By the way, I saw many solution which is put the navigation drawer before `toolbar` in xml, but I using androidmanifest to set `actionbar`. Any solution for set the navigation drawer cover over the support action bar?

**style.xml:**

```
<style name="custom_actionbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">40dp</item>
</style>
```

**androidmanifest.xml:**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FoodActivity"
        android:label="Food"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/custom_actionbar"/>
```

**xml code:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mm"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absolutex="8dp">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/highlightTV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/today_hightlight"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/highlightGV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/highlightTV"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/leftGl"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/rightGl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomGl"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topRatedTV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/top_rated"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/highlightGV"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/topRatedGV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="720dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topRatedTV"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>



    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topGl"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.015"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottomGl"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topGl2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.375"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottomGl2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.975"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/leftGl"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0225"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rightGl"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9775"/>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/goFoodBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/swipe_food"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_fork"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_fork"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_knife"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_knife"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingStart="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingEnd="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
<!--Buttons in Lollipop and higher have a default elevation to them
 which causes them to always draw on top.
You can change this by overriding the default StateListAnimator.-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/findFoodFL"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: For me helped: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` parameter on `NavigationView` XML item.

Comment: @Dumbo Thanks you, I have added but still not working.

Comment: Not the perfect solution ..but it works .if you have your toolbaar size as 40dp, then give property android:layout_marginTop="-40dp" to NavigationView or according to your toolbaar size change the value

Comment: @matinsayyad that why I wanted to cover the actionbar, and is android:layout_marginTop="40dp" to NavigationView not -40dp, -40dp will push up the navigation bar.